# Округление целого числа до значения делящегося на 10 без остатка? (Округление к большему по модулю)

Tags: c++, qt

Возможно округлить `41-49 до 50` пример 41 до 50, 43 до 50 или 49 до 50. Или к примеру -41 до -50 , `-41 - -49 до -50`. Надо для отображения нормальной шкалы на графиках.

Comment: это [Округление к большему по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (c точностью до `-1`-го знака после запятой)

Comment: @jfs  Округление к большему по модулю , это не совсем то . Так как мне надо было округлять и числа с минусом (-41 - -49 до -50) к меньшему.

Comment: как раз то, вы наверное не то определение посмотрели. "большее по модулю" число может быть меньше (округление в сторону бесконечности, от нуля). Если сомневаетесь, то пример приведите. `-50` больше по модулю, чем `-49`: `abs(-50) > abs(-49)`

Comment: @jfs А всё точно ,  я просто не внимательно прочитал. Ключевое слово модуль. Я понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делить число n + 9 умноженное на знак числа, нацело на 10, а потом умножать на 10

```
int res = (int) ((9 * (n / abs(n)) + n) / 10) * 10
```

Где `n/abs(n)` = знаку числа n (-1 или 1) (это для того что бы учитывать отрицательные числа)

Comment: и что будет ? 42+9= 51 разделить на 10 будет 5,1 и умножить на 10 будет 51 . А мне надо чтоб было 50

Comment: Вчитайтесь, НАЦЕЛО (это значит отбрасывать дробную часть)

Comment: хорошая задумка сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: Рад помочь)
Только вот все же заминочка со знаком, щас разберусь и сделаю поправку

Comment: Да делить отрицательное на отрицательное положительное )

Comment: Если вы знак найти хотите, используйте `n/abs(n)`. Но я даже не знаю. Может вместо деления и модуля быстрее будет просто тернарный оператор?

Comment: @selya модуль да, можно так

Comment: да я сейчас правлю. Спасибо !

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще решение - более интуитивное:

```
int result = (int)(ceil(N * 0.1) * 10);
```

Смысл такой: берем число, делим на 10. Находим ближайшее целое, большее получившегося. Умножаем на 10.

(Правда при таком подходе с отрицательными числами не выйдет, как вы хотите, ибо ближайшее целое, больше -4.1 - это -4).

Если все же хочется довести этот вариант до нужного вам поведения, то делаем примерно так:

```
int result = (int)(ceil(abs(N) * 0.1) * 10) * (N > 0 ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: Ну тоже как вариант

Comment: Не совсем то поведение например 41 округляет до 40 , а мне надо до 50 .... ТАк как максимум у меня 40,8 и округление до 40 обрезает верх графика

Comment: @IvanTriumphov я тестировал в консоли на JS, было норм. Решил проверить, что происходит на c++. Почему-то функция `abs` на c++ в этом случае отсекает дробную часть, и это странно. Секунду, разберусь

Comment: @IvanTriumphov исправил. Почему-то функция `abs` возвращает `int` в c++. Поправил скобочки, теперь работает.

Comment: Да спасибо большое). Но я уже накидал рабочий вариант для себя Bogdan первым предложил рабочий вариант. Так что я его вариант отмечу как ответ на вопрос. Ваш вариант я тоже отметил плюсом )

Comment: @IvanTriumphov угу, мой вариант просто как альтернатива. А так, первый вариант должен быть и быстрее в плане вычисления, ибо нет ненужных преобразований.

Comment: Эх, и всё-таки, использование чисел с плавающей точкой в ситуациях, когда требуется точный результат чревато потенциальными ошибками. Сравните: [пример 1](https://ideone.com/aEEtSU), [пример 2](https://ideone.com/x1C71j).  Примеры конечно надуманные, но всё же.

Comment: @wololo это верно, но пример и не стремится быть рабочим во всех случаях, лишь демонстрирует один из возможных вариантов)

Comment: Да, я ж говорю, надуманный пример)